# Is there any performance gain in running mvc 6 on fullstack .net over mvc 5 when hosting on Azure

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure

There is an interesting [benchmarks](https://github.com/aspnet/benchmarks) page on the officail asp.net github.

It says that .net 4.6 on IIS produces 47k rps, but ASP.NET Core on Kestrel 1.15 M rps.

So assuming I will write new app to host on Azure, is there any performance benefit of using MVC 6 on dotnet46 target?

Comment: MVC Core 1.0 is very different from MVC 5, not only for performance. So of course you'll benefit from e.g. the dependency injection model and most likely get performance. But specifics depend on what you're doing.